# What are some references discussing the generation of quantum circuits with genetic algorithms?

Tags: resource-request, quantum-circuit

I have recently saw that quantum circuits can be generated using genetic algorithms. These are called as Evolvable quantum hardware. Please provide me some links of good papers or books related on this topic.

Comment: You mean like a random quantum circuit?

Comment: Hi @R.W, I am aware that there some ways to generate quantum circuit using genetic algorithm. I do not have any resource to know about the work done in this field. Can I get some resource/links to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely not going to be a comprehensive list but I may give a starting point that others can build upon. Hope this is helpful.

- [Quantum Circuits Engineering: Efficient Simulation and Reconfigurable Quantum Hardware, PhD thesis](http://acsa.upt.ro/publications/ThesisMU.pdf)

Often when starting to learn about a particular topic I find helpful to look into PhD thesis or even Master dissertations because students tend to be long winded about their topics, with long and explanations and discussions. This PhD thesis can guide you to many references from GoogleScholar. To start, it also has an entire section on the topic you've mentioned, while also being nice in introducing concepts in quantum computing. Note that this thesis points in the introduction to many books and standard references.

- [Implementing quantum genetic algorithms: a solution based on Grover's algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1128022.1128034)

Of the same author, I thought interesting to see this kind of application of QC in Genetic ALgorithms. These two have guided me towards more recent applications and developments.

- [Quantum-Inspired Evolutionary Algorithms on
  IBM Quantum Experience](https://web.s.ebscohost.com/ehost/pdfviewer/pdfviewer?vid=0&sid=badae3e5-ef82-41bc-b2a8-3917d387bc4c%40redis)
- [A New Quantum Inspired Genetic Algorithm for Evolvable Hardware](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5628539)

Where you have implementation and development of state-of-the-art algorithms.

**Disclaimer:** I am not an expert, I have only tried to help you in your search, simply because I found interesting that such attempts already exist given the state of QC as a field. Hopefully more experienced people will jump in and make helpful comments, while also address further points and improvements.

Att.